# Step failed with exitCode, Amazon Emr Hadoop, S3DistCp

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hadoop2, amazon-emr, s3distcp

I'm trying to create a "Step" and gather many small files into one, so I can separate it for days. The problem is that I'm intetando run and not let me.

Executing it works well for me command:

```
hadoop distcp s3n://buket-name/output-files-hive/* s3n://buket-name/files-hive/test
```

But then if I already entered commands "group by" or "srcPattern" it does not make me anything.

After creating the "Step" in the Amazon EMR console, giving me all the time error. You indicated the file

Command:

```
aws emr add-steps --cluster-id j-XXXXXXX --steps Name="S3DistCp step",Jar="command-runner.jar",Args=["spark-submit","--src=s3n://buket-name/output-files-hive/output-files-hive/*","--dest=s3n://buket-name/output-files-hive/files-hive/test/"]
```

Error:

```
2016-07-13T15:06:27.677Z INFO Ensure step 3 jar file command-runner.jar
2016-07-13T15:06:27.678Z INFO StepRunner: Created Runner for step 3
INFO startExec 'hadoop jar /var/lib/aws/emr/step-runner/hadoop-jars/command-runner.jar spark-submit --src=s3n://buket-name/output-files-hive/* --dest=s3n://buket-name/files-hive/test/'
INFO Environment:
  TERM=linux
  CONSOLETYPE=serial
  SHLVL=5
  JAVA_HOME=/etc/alternatives/jre
  HADOOP_IDENT_STRING=hadoop
  LANGSH_SOURCED=1
  XFILESEARCHPATH=/usr/dt/app-defaults/%L/Dt
  HADOOP_ROOT_LOGGER=INFO,DRFA
  AWS_CLOUDWATCH_HOME=/opt/aws/apitools/mon
  UPSTART_JOB=rc
  MAIL=/var/spool/mail/hadoop
  EC2_AMITOOL_HOME=/opt/aws/amitools/ec2
  PWD=/
  HOSTNAME=ip-172-31-21-173
  LESS_TERMCAP_se=[0m
  LOGNAME=hadoop
  UPSTART_INSTANCE=
  AWS_PATH=/opt/aws
  LESS_TERMCAP_mb=[01;31m
  _=/etc/alternatives/jre/bin/java
  LESS_TERMCAP_me=[0m
  NLSPATH=/usr/dt/lib/nls/msg/%L/%N.cat
  LESS_TERMCAP_md=[01;38;5;208m
  runlevel=3
  AWS_AUTO_SCALING_HOME=/opt/aws/apitools/as
  UPSTART_EVENTS=runlevel
  HISTSIZE=1000
  previous=N
  HADOOP_LOGFILE=syslog
  PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/opt/aws/bin
  EC2_HOME=/opt/aws/apitools/ec2
  HADOOP_LOG_DIR=/mnt/var/log/hadoop/steps/s-2SKUUYYPQ4KKK
  LESS_TERMCAP_ue=[0m
  AWS_ELB_HOME=/opt/aws/apitools/elb
  RUNLEVEL=3
  USER=hadoop
  HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS=-Djava.io.tmpdir=/mnt/var/lib/hadoop/steps/s-2SKUUYYPQ4KKK/tmp
  PREVLEVEL=N
  HOME=/home/hadoop
  HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
  LESSOPEN=||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
  AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-1
  LANG=en_US.UTF-8
  LESS_TERMCAP_us=[04;38;5;111m
INFO redirectOutput to /mnt/var/log/hadoop/steps/s-2SKUUYYPQ4KKK/stdout
INFO redirectError to /mnt/var/log/hadoop/steps/s-2SKUUYYPQ4KKK/stderr
INFO Working dir /mnt/var/lib/hadoop/steps/s-2SKUUYYPQ4KKK
INFO ProcessRunner started child process 7836 :
hadoop    7836  2229  0 15:06 ?        00:00:00 bash /usr/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop jar /var/lib/aws/emr/step-runner/hadoop-jars/command-runner.jar spark-submit --src=s3n://buket-name/output-files-hive/* --dest=s3n://buket-name/files-hive/test/
2016-07-13T15:06:31.724Z INFO HadoopJarStepRunner.Runner: startRun() called for s-2SKUUYYPQ4KKK Child Pid: 7836
INFO Synchronously wait child process to complete : hadoop jar /var/lib/aws/emr/step-runner/hadoop-...
INFO waitProcessCompletion ended with exit code 1 : hadoop jar /var/lib/aws/emr/step-runner/hadoop-...
INFO total process run time: 2 seconds
2016-07-13T15:06:31.991Z INFO Step created jobs: 
2016-07-13T15:06:31.992Z WARN Step failed with exitCode 1 and took 2 seconds
```

Answer (score -1):

In the new version of emr amazon it is no longer necesartio include the .jar file, define S3DistCp the argument goes.

```
aws emr add-steps --cluster-id j-XXXXXX --steps Name="S3DistCp step V3",Jar="command-runner.jar",Args=["s3-dist-cp","--src=s3n://buket-name/output-files-hive/","--dest=s3n://buket-name/files-hive/test/"]
```